# Cleanly filter a list of EitherT to find value of subtype

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I have a list of EitherT values. I would like to determine if a `Right` value of a specific subtype exists in this list. The following provides a toy example.

```scala
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.implicits._

sealed trait Animal {
  def name: String
}
case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal
case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal

val listOfAnimals: List[Either[Throwable, Animal]] = List(Right(Cat("Snowball")), Right(Dog("Mr. Growls")))

listOfAnimals
  .map(_.toEitherT[IO])
  .existsM(_ exists {
      case _: Cat => true
      case _      => false
    })
  .unsafeRunSync()
```

The cleanest code I have come up with so far is the above `existsM` usage. Is there a cleaner / more concise way? Note that I *do not* want to sequence the list of EitherT values.

Comment: looks like too complicated an approach, why just not : listOfAnimals.map(x => x match {
      case Right(Cat(_)) => true
      case _ => false
    })

Comment: @Pavel Unfortunately, I'm dealing with a list of EitherT's rather than a list of Either's. Because my snippet above is a toy example, I explicitly converted `listOfAnimals` to a list of EitherT[IO]. However, in my actual code, that's something I don't have control over - I must work with a list of EitherT.